# ARM Assembly: How to pass and make use of a array of pointers inside an ARM Assembly function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, assembly, arm

I have a C function in which I have 4 pointers and each of them point to different locations of a large 2D array of floats.

Because the ARM assembly functions can only be passed with 4 parameters (r0 - r3), I'm not able to understand how to pass the pointer to my return value, which will become the 5th parameter to my assembly function.

So, to overcome this, I thought of putting all the 4 pointers into an array of pointers, so that I will have 3 more free spots, using which I can pass a pointer to my return value as well.

But, I don't know how I can extract the four individual pointers from my array of pointers, inside the assembly function. I'm failing in my attempts.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do.

### Program

```
#include<stdio.h>

void  _my_arm_asm(float32_t *);

float32_t data_array[100][100];

void main()
{
       float32_t *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3, *ptr4;

        ptr1 = \\ data_array[value] + (some value);
        ptr2 = \\ data_array[value] + (some other value);
        ptr3 = \\ data_array[value] + (some other value);
        ptr4 = \\ data_array[value] + (some other value);

       float32_t *array_pointers[4];
       array_pointers[0] = ptr1;
       array_pointers[1] = ptr2;
       array_pointers[2] = ptr3;
       array_pointers[3] = ptr4;

       float32x4_t result;

       _my_arm_asm(array_pointers, &result);

        ....
        ....
        ....
       return 0;


}



.text
    .global _my_arm_asm

_my_arm_asm:
            #r0: Pointer to my array of pointers
            #r1: Pointer to my result

        push   {r4-r11, lr}

        # How to access the array of pointers?

        # I previously tried this, is this the right way to do it?

        # mov r4, #0
        # vld4.32 {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [r0, r4]
        # add r4, r4, #1
        # vld4.32 {d4, d5, d6, d7}, [r0, r4] 
        # add r4, r4, #1
        # vld4.32 {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [r0, r4] 
        # add r4, r4, #1
        # vld4.32 {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [r0, r4] 


        ....
        ....
        ....

        pop    {r4-r11, pc}
```

Comment: You should show what you're trying on the assembly side.

Comment: When faced with this kind of problem the best approach is to write a stub function in C and then compile it to assembler source with `gcc -S` - you can then use the generated assembler source as a template for your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if more than 4 arguments are passed to a function the excess arguments are passed on the stack.

The ARM EABI specifies how compilers should pass arguments to functions (it also specifies which registers a caller can expect to be unchanged across the function call).  Your assembly routine can use the same techniques (and probably should unless you have a good reason not to).  If nothing else, that'll mean that your assembly function can be easily called from C.

- http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html

Chapter 5 (The Base procedure Call Standard) of the "Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture" should have the exact details. It's pretty complex on the face of it (becuase there's a lot of detail on alignment, argument size, etc), but I think for your purposes it boils down to that the 5th argument to the function get's pushed onto the stack.

- http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf

Of course, as you suggest in your question, you could avoid all that by packing your 4 pointers into a structure and passing a pointer to the struct - in your assembly routine you simple load that struct pointer into a register and use that to in turn load the pointers you really need.

I think that the ARM assembly might look something like:

```
                 // r0 has the 1st parameter
ldr r4, [r0]     // get array_pointers[0] into r4
// ...

ldr r5, [r0, #4] // get array_pointers[1] into r5
// ...

ldr r6, [r0, #8] // get array_pointers[2] into r6
```

You could also use a 'load multiple' instruction to get all 4 pointers in one shot, but I'm not sure what you register usage requirements/restrictions might be.

Comment: Michael, yes, I did what you have suggested, I packed all the pointers into a structure and passed it to the assembly function and I could access them using ldr's.

Answer (score 3):

The fifth and further parameters (assuming int-sized parameters) are passed on stack. I.e. the fifth parameter will be accessible as [SP], the sixth as [SP,#4] and so on. Read the [Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/index.html) for the detailed explanations.
That said, you don't have to use assembly to make use of NEON. Check out [NEON intrinsics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html) which allow you to do all operations using plain C code.